# To show that $P(|X-Y| \leq 2) \leq 3P(|X-Y| \leq 1)$

Tags: probability, inequality

I found this question while browsing through "The Probabilistic Method", by Noga Elon.

Let X and Y be 2 independent and identically distributed real valued random variables. Prove that:
$$P(|X-Y| \leq 2) \leq 3P(|X-Y| \leq 1)$$

So I tried the following:

$$P\{|X-Y| \leq 2\} = P\{|X-Y| \leq 1\} + P\{X-Y \in (1,2]\cup[-2,-1)\}$$
$$= P\{|X-Y| \leq 1\} + P\{X-Y \in (1,2]\} + P\{X-Y \in [-2,-1)\}$$
$$= P\{|X-Y| \leq 1\} + 2P\{X-Y \in (1,2]\}$$
where the last step follows because $X-Y$ has a symmetric distribution. NB: A random variable Z has symmetric distribution if 
$$P(Z \leq z) = P(Z \geq -z) \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{R}$$

Thus the problem boils down to showing
$$P\{X-Y \in (1,2]\} \leq P(|X-Y| \leq 1)$$
and I would be done. Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed from here. I appreciate any help, hints, useful comments etc. I receive.

Comment: What does iid mean?

Comment: independent and identically distributed. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proof is given in ["The 123 Theorem and its extensions" by Noga Alon, Raphael Yuster](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.57.8591). (See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/random-variable-inequality).)

Comment: The '123 theorem' looks so simple. The solution seems really wicked! I have been trying this problem for four days now :(