# Let be X and Y two real random variables, independents with the same distribution.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need to show the next proposition:

Let be X and Y real random variables, independents with the same distribution, so $Pr(\vert X-Y\vert\leq2)\leq3Pr(\vert X-Y\vert\leq1)$

Comment: When is this due?

Comment: i have not idea, how to prove this.

Comment: Taking X and Y random variables, the problem is show that Pr(|X−Y|≤2)≤3Pr(|X−Y|≤1)

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15251/279515, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244362/279515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem in Probabilistic Method by Spencer and Alon. It is a starred problem in the first chapter. For a reference there is a blog with solutions to some of the problems, which you can find here [solution manual](https://radimentary.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/solutions_compilation.pdf)
look for problem $3$.

If you want a hint/sketch to start, try showing if you have $n$ real numbers that 
$\# \{ (x_i,x_j) |   |x_i-x_j|\leq 2     \} \leq 3\# \{ (x_i,x_j) |   |x_i-x_j|\leq 1    \}$.

Then sample $X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n$ I.I.D.,
now the previous lemma implies
$E( \# (i,j) : |X_i -X_j| \leq2  )\leq 3E( \# (i,j) : |X_i -X_j| \leq 1  )$. And finally take $n\rightarrow \infty$ and conclude.